# Excel Formula To Get First and Last Non-Zero Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have checked the similar questions but they are little bit different from what I need to do.
What I need to do is create a summary table for large data, some of that data is this:

```
[A] [B]    [C]      [D]
17-07-14            182
    U   16-01-14    3
        28-03-14    4
        03-04-14    4

    L   27-01-14    1
        29-01-14    4
        31-01-14    8
        12-02-14    4
        17-02-14    10
        21-02-14    6
        04-04-14    5
        17-07-14    1

    I   05-02-14    7
        12-02-14    4
        24-02-14    8
        24-03-14    3

    O   17-02-14    3
        25-02-14    5
        03-03-14    4
        05-03-14    5
        07-03-14    6
        11-03-14    2
        23-06-14    6

    N   07-03-14    1
        11-03-14    2
        12-03-14    5
        13-03-14    2
        17-03-14    8
        18-03-14    2
        05-05-14    1
        13-05-14    2
        10-06-14    1
        14-07-14    2
```

Now what I need is, for each Letter (U, L, I), I need the first date [C], last date [C], total count [D]. If anyone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Show please what have you already achieved, I assume you try a VBA solution? And what you mean by "I need the first date ..." - do you want to write it in a cell of table?

Comment: No I don't want VBA solution....

Comment: So far, I used this solution (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/returning-the-first-and-last-item-in-a-subset-in-excel/) I got the first value but the last value its fetching is not correct.

Comment: A link to a method doesn't show what you've tried already. Show us what you have and what you're missing. Otherwise I'd say just use a `max` and `min` and a `sum`. Or do you need them to automatically know what letter they are? This is very vague. Maybe try a pivot table?

Comment: If you are okay to manually clean up the table first like remove blank rows (Filter -> Blank -> delete rows) and populate all applicable cells in column with alphabets (U,L,I etc)  with respective values. Then  create a separate table with unique values (Advanced Filter)  then you can use VLOOKUP to get the first value. SUMIF to get the respective count for each unique value. To get last value you can use INDEX. First get the count of all unique alphabets and create a cumulative index column and run INDEX on date column starting with first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Raystafarian suggests, a pivot table will do what you require :

- First you will need to clean up the blank rows
- Then you will need to fill up the empty cells by copying down (I use
  the formula here : `=if(len(A3)>0,A3,F2)` which basically checks for
  an empty cell...if its empty, copy the cell above, else use the value
  in that cell. This will produce the following table :

[image]

- Finally, create a pivot table with the columns you require (Min, Max,
  Sum) :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. First I would add a row at the top with column titles. I would start the Power Query using the From Table button. The first step in the Query would be to select the Letter column and choose Fill Down.  Then next step would be to choose Group By, adding a Min and Max columns based on the Date, and adding a Sum column based on your count [D] column. I think that's all you would need.